# Opening image using Gallery does not show the Share option

Tags: android

In my app, I am opening my image using this code:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(picPathUriString)), "image/png");
        startActivity(intent);
```

I run it on S2 and it opens the picture using the gallery as expected and showing all the capabilities of that gallery app (such as "Share" and "Send" ..etc)

On the S4, it shows the picture but the above options  such as SHARE are not there. Although the Gallery on S4 has all the options if opened seperately

WHYYY? How can I make sure  I get all the options?
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Snake - Indeed, the answer does not perform what you (and me) want. So did you solve this somehow? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @not really, I just had to change the requirement to show share button  outside of gallery

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
     Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
     shareIntent.setType("image/png"); 
     shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET); 
     Uri uri = Uri.parse(Uri.parse(picPathUriString)); 
     shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); 
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
```

Comment: But this will ask the user to share the right away. I want to show the picture and the user can then press setting  button and  share